# Create a list of substrings from string

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, substring

I have this string:

```
"<C (programming language)> <C++ (programming language)> <Programming Languages> <Computer Programming> "
```

And i want to obtain a list of substrings, like this:

```
['<C (programming language)>','<C++ (programming language)>','<Programming Languages>','<Computer Programming>']
```

I tried to use **re library python** but without success

Comment: What regular expressions have you tried so far? Are you able to extract at least one substring, e.g. just the first: "<C (programming language)>"?

Comment: I have tried re.search or re.match for find all substrings with this feature <sub-string>
So i use this pattern <.*?> but i have no match.

Comment: `<.*?>` should have worked, as you have correctly used the non-greedy `*?`. Try that with the answer you picked. But this greedy `*` vs. non-greedy `*?` is always confusing, so I'd also go with the much clearer `<[^>]*>` or `<[^>]+>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using regular expressions, you can use:

```
import re
regexp = re.compile("<[^>]+>")
matches = regexp.findall(my_string)
```

The regular expression basically matches everything starting with a '<' and ending with a '>'. `findall` then returns all found matches.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the re import, although another solution would be to use the split method as shown here:

```
st = st.split('>')  # splits the string to a list made of elements divided by the '>' sign but deletes the '>' sign
del st[len(st) - 1]  # Splitting your String like we did will add another unneccesary element in the end of the list
st = [i + ">" for i in st]  # adds back the '>' sign to the every element of the list
```

Hope it helped